# is Jwt token was UNIQUE

Tags: php, laravel, jwt, laravel-authorization

I'm using JWT web token system. I was able to generate TOKENS successfully.
I'm creating JWT tokens in Laravel as follows

> I'M USING FOLLOWING TECHNOLOGY STACK

- [LARAVEL 5.2](http://laravel.com/) framework
- JWT [(package)](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth)

> SAMPLE CODE

```
use JWTAuth;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException;

class AuthenticateController extends Controller
{
    public function authenticate(Request $request)
    {
        // grab credentials from the request
        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

        try {
            // attempt to verify the credentials and create a token for the user
            if (! $token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) {
                return response()->json(['error' => 'invalid_credentials'], 401);
            }
        } catch (JWTException $e) {
            // something went wrong whilst attempting to encode the token
            return response()->json(['error' => 'could_not_create_token'], 500);
        }

        // all good so return the token
        return response()->json(compact('token'));
    }
}
```

> SAMPLE OUTPUT

I'm GETTING

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiYWRtaW4iOnRydWV9.TJVA95OrM7E2cBab30RMHrHDcEfxjoYZgeFONFh7HgQ
```

> QUESTION 1

**Is the generated token is UNIQUE?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JWT is unique in a way that no two same users can have the same token generated for them

Comment: How JWT token was unique i.e., on what parameters token was UNIQUE (whether its due to HEADER or PAYLOAD or SIGNATURE)?

Comment: Header payload and signature together make a token. You have no real security issue if someone finds one part of the whole token. But header is the same, the other two change. Check the [link](https://jwt.io/) and try to change values and see what happens

Comment: How can I make user token is valid for a period between successful login and logout ?

Comment: I think you shuld have a `remember_token` field in Laravel User model by default. Once you create the token, you can store it in that field, and upon logout you simply delete it. After next login, user will get another token generated, and so you repeat the process

Comment: That makes sense , But how can i set Jwt Token to be expired or destroyed after succesfull logout only? not before successful logout

Comment: It should be done so after you call the `logout()` method/route. If you're using Laravel 5 and `php artisan make:auth`, you should find the `logout()` method in AuthenticatesUsers trait. If you're using PHPStorm IDE, you can do double-shift and type logout...or getLogout

Comment: I'm asking how to set JWT token to be destroyed

Comment: Find the authenticated user, and set his token field property to null

Comment: Yes I found a way to destroy accesss token  by using       **JWTAuth::setToken($token)->invalidate();**,

Comment: Thank you I have got perfect solution to above problem.

Comment: Just found out that the `remember_token` can't actually be used like that...it is used for prevention of cookie hijacking...but you got it :)

Comment: Yes, I know that , In Laravel remeber toke field is used to store XSRF (Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF)).

Comment: Currently I'm storing JWT token in Mysql DB with VARCHAR data type of size 255 (maximum size). Is it sufficient to store JWT.i.e, VARCHAR(255)

Answer (score 4):

In general, JWT is actually replacing the combination of username and password. What it means, instead of keep sending username and password for each request for a restricted resources, the server will return a unique token after verifying the the credentials is correct on the first time the user login. Afterwards, every request will includes the token which will be checked as valid or not before fulfilling the request.

So, if two user comes in and login with two valid credentials, it will receive two different token from the server.